# How to use Nest.js's @Headers properly?

Tags: node.js, http-headers, nestjs

According to the [controller docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/controllers) I can use `@Headers(param?: string)` or `req.headers` or `req.headers[param]` to get header value. I tried the first approach, I have following in my request headers from Postman

```
Content-Type:application/json
My-Id:test12345
```

I have following controller sample code

```
@Put('/aa/:aa/bb/:bb/')
@UsePipes(new ValidationPipe({ transform: true }))
public async DoMyJob(@Body() request: MyRequestDto,
                                @Param('aa') aa: number,
                                @Param('bb') bb: string,
                                @Headers('My-Id') id: string): Promise<MyResponseDto> {
    // More code here
}
```

When I set break point to inspect the value from `My-Id` header it is undefined.

So how shall I do in Nest.Js properly to get the header value from RESTful service client?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Headers will be sent in lower case so you need `@Headers('my-id')` instead.

---

Easy to debug by injecting the full headers object:

```
import { Headers } from '@nestjs/common';
...
@Put('/')
public async put(@Headers() headers) {
    console.log(headers);
}
```

The `headers` variable will then refer to the [`req.headers`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_message_headers).

Answer (score 4):

Implementation of @Headers decorator. This can help you to create your own custom decorators:

```
import { IncomingMessage } from 'http';
import { createParamDecorator, ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common';

const Header = createParamDecorator((name: string, ctx: ExecutionContext): string | undefined => {
    const req = ctx.switchToHttp().getRequest<IncomingMessage>();
    const { headers } = req;

    return headers[name] as string;
});
```

If you want to create a custom decorator based on Headers:

```
const IsMobileClient = createParamDecorator((_: never, ctx: ExecutionContext): boolean => {
    const req = ctx.switchToHttp().getRequest<IncomingMessage>();
    const isMobile = req.headers['user-agent']?.toLowerCase().includes('mobi');

    return Boolean(isMobile);
});
```

And usage example:

```
@Get()
public async yourRequest(
    @Header('cookie') cookie?: string,
    @IsMobileClient() isMobile: boolean,
): Promise<any> {
    console.log(cookie, isMobile);
    // ...other code
}
```

Comment: I was trying to use ```return headers[someString] as string```, but I can't send it to the api. Can you explain how you send a header like this from postman?